# Spring mvc bean acts as controller without @Controller declaration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can any one please explain me the difference between declaring a class with @Controller vs (declaring it with @Scope + define a bean in the applicationContext.xml)

Here is my situation.

**Approach 1**: declare the class with @Scope and add bean definition in the applicationContext.xml

AbcController.java:

```
package my.app.controller;
    @Scope("singleton")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/abc")
    public class AbcController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/simulate_abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getFactorsForSimulate(ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("Welcome to the simulations page");
            return "simulate_abc";
        }
    }
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="abcController" class="my.app.controller.AbcController"/>
```

**Approach 2**: declare the class with @Controller and no bean definition in applicationContext.xml

```
package my.app.controller;    
@Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/abc")
    public class AbcController {
           @RequestMapping(value = "/simulate_abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String getFactorsForSimulate(ModelMap model) {
                model.addAttribute("Welcome to the simulations page");
                return "simulate_abc";
         }
    }
```

Here, both the approaches are giving me the expected results (taking me to 'simulate_abc.jsp' with the message attached to the model). I would like to understand, why is **Approach1** not failing? Although it has a RequestMapping, since it is not declared as a controller, how come the 'view' is getting resolved?
I have a feeling that the **Approach1** is wrong, as it does not satisfy 'C' part in the spring 'MVC'.

Comment: You can notify the user that marked it like so: @Luiggi.

Comment: @Luiggi.
May I know why the question is tagged duplicate? Provided link does not seem to answer my question. I found the issue. The views are getting resolved due to the declaration 'RequestMapping' for the method. And  I am sure, this is NOT a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

For `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` there is no difference, just look at [RequestMappingHandlerMapping#isHandler()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java), both annotations works.

However, for others `HandlerMappings` like in `AbstractControllerUrlHandlerMapping` hierarchy, `@Controller` annotation does the matter.

Note that in Spring MVC a Controller is **any class** with **any method** that a `HandlerMapping` maps to a request. A `HandlerAdapter` is also needed to execute it.